# Android WiFi state is UNKNOWN

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I had a problem when i tried to return the wifi state , disconnected or connected ..  well I dont get an exception but it jumps to the else {} block of my if condition, when i was debugging I found that :

```
 NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

mWifi has this: NetworkInfo: type: wifi[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified)

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);


        if (mWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()){

            Toast.makeText(this,"void action Working", 3).show();



        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"void action Not working", 3).show();

        }
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but, what is your question here?

Comment: my question is i can't test if wifi is connected or what state is in, i dont get and error but when debugging i found this :

  NetworkInfo: type: wifi[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
            final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) YourActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 

            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {

                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); //If it's, off turn it on.

            }else{

                //Do what you want to do with wi-fi.            

            }
```

Note also that I have the following permissions set in my manifest (perhaps not all of which are required in your case as I'm implementing wifi direct functionality):

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: the app crashed :/ , and by the way ,i changed your  SplashActivity to just this

Comment: Put your host activity's name in. I've made an edit to make it clearer.

Comment: it's a service ... but it did not work , again crashed

Comment: thats right , my code was okay , i was using 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

and i added what you gave me , and it works perfect , thank you :)